# How do I resolve "undeclared identifier" error from the code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ and I ran the following code in Visual Studio  2019.
I am getting 12 errors , but the code runs fine on the website.

You can find the code here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

class Box{
public:
    static int objectCount;

    //Constructor definition
    Box(double l = 2.0 double b = 2.0 double h = 2.0) {
        cout << "Constructor Called." << endl;
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
        height = h;

        //Increase everytime the object is created
        objectCount++;
    }
    double Volume() {
        return length * breadth* height;
    }
private:
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;
};
// Initialize static member of class Box
int Box::objectCount = 0;

int main(void) {
    Box Box1(3.3, 1.2, 1.5);
    Box Box2(8.5, 6.0, 2.0);

    cout << "Total objects: " << Box::objectCount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: `Box(double l = 2.0 double = 2.0 double h = 2.0) {` You need commas. `Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0) {` You also forgot a name for 2nd param.

Comment: A tip: never sort your compiler warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the constructor of `Box` Class. You just missed `,` between parameters and name of `b`.

```
Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0) {
```

Please see the full code as following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box {
public:
    static int objectCount;

    //Constructor definition
    Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0) {
        cout << "Constructor Called." << endl;
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
        height = h;

        //Increase everytime the object is created
        objectCount++;
    }
    double Volume() {
        return length * breadth* height;
    }
private:
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;
};
// Initialize static member of class Box
int Box::objectCount = 0;

int main(void) {
    Box Box1(3.3, 1.2, 1.5);
    Box Box2(8.5, 6.0, 2.0);

    cout << "Total objects: " << Box::objectCount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please get your result as following:

```
Constructor Called.
Constructor Called.
Total objects: 2
```